# Как получить 1 запись из цикла?

Tags: php, wordpress

помогите в решении вопроса. На сайте работает плагин Yarpp, он выводит 5 похожих записей в конце страницы. Есть необходимость в получении 1-й записи из цикла похожих и удалении ее из цикла. Для того, чтобы вывести эту запись в другом месте на странице. Не могу понять как это сделать. Буду благодарен любым советам, в php не очень силен. Заранее спасибо!
Вот текущий код цикла:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
<div class="related">
  <p class="heading">Похожие записи</p>
  <div class="related__items">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    $related = true;
    include 'shab.php';
    $related = false;
    ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Сам вывод похожих записей осуществляется кодом:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'related_posts' ) ) related_posts();  ?>
```

В файле shab.php находится шаблон для вывода записей:

```
    <div class="item">

  <div class="item__image-wrap"><?php
    item_thumb( array(
      'width'  => 400,
      'height' => 200,
      'class'  => 'item__image',
    ) );
  ?></div>

<?php if ( ! is_category() ) { ?>
  <a class="item__cat" href="<?php $category = get_the_category(); $cat_id = $category[0]->cat_ID; echo get_category_link( $cat_id ); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?></a>
<?php } ?>

  <div class="item__inner">

    <a class="item__title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

  <?php if ( ! $related ) { ?>
    <p class="item__text"><noindex><?php echo ( has_excerpt() ) ? get_the_excerpt() : wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 15, ' ...' ); ?></noindex></p>

    <a class="item__more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">Читать далее</a>
  <?php } ?>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: А что у вас в файле  include 'shab.php';?

Comment: Шаблон для оформления выводимых записей

Comment: Добавил информацию по шаблону к стартовому посту

Comment: Мб я не так понимаю задачу, но если известно какую запись надо "пропустить" и есть шаблон вывода, не вариант проверять ID записи в шаблоне и если он равен той, которую выводить не надо, просто пропускать ее мимо цикла с генерацией HTML кода?

Comment: Я не знаю какую именно запись вывести. Плагин YARPP автоматически подбирает для каждой страницы свой список похожих записей. Задача в том, чтобы получить первую запись из этого списка и исключить ее из цикла.

Comment: Можно сделать костыльно. Добавить перед циклом переменную (к примеру $i =1) и сделать проверку в конце цикла. Если она равна 1, заканчиваем цикл.